# Opening Data from Excel in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, excel

I am trying to select some data from Excel into my SQL query.

I have the following query:

```
SELECT*
FROM
openrowset('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
            'Excel 12.0;Database=S:\Nh\NHData.xlsx;',
            'SELECT *
             FROM [Pre Upgrade data$]') as t2
```

If I run this on my local SQL server instance, it works fine, however to get it to work, I had to follow the procedure outlined on the below link, setting the SQL server service to run as my user account.
http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/The-OLE-DB-provider-Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB.12.0-for-linked-server-null.aspx

Without changing the user, I would get the following error:

Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)".

For obvious reasons I cannot change the SQL server user on my live SQL database server.

How can I get this to run?

Comment: Did you try this:
Grant rigths to TEMP directory: http://www.excel-sql-server.com/excel-import-to-sql-server-using-linked-servers.htm

Comment: I now get the following:

Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "ExcelServer2" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.
Msg 7303, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "ExcelServer2".

Comment: This means that your user have no rights for SQL Server TEMP directory. Can you check these directories: 
(For network instance) C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\AppData\Local\Temp
(For local instance)
C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\LocalService\AppData\Local\Temp
and confirm if your user have read/write access?
Also make sure you file isn't open.

Comment: The account used by SQL server has full access to both those folders and still the same.
http://s21.postimg.org/8mrqkcizr/Sql_users.png

Comment: And you are sure your Excel file is closed? Also what is the format of your excel file?  Excel 97-2003 or 2007?
Another thing, go to linked server folder and then providers right click on "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" go to properties and uncheck the "allow inprocess".

Comment: The file is definitely closed. File is XLSM so 2007 format.
Unticking that option didn't make a difference

Comment: Did you configure your Ace correctly with these:

`EXEC sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', N'AllowInProcess', 1
GO 
EXEC sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', N'DynamicParameters', 1
GO`
These steps are working fine for me

Comment: Yes, I've done that previously. I've just set them again, and still get the same result.
Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "ExcelServer2" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.
Msg 7303, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "ExcelServer2".